# Data services client async load DataGridView

Tags: .net, asynchronous, datagridview, wcf-data-services, wcf-data-services-client

I have a Web API Odata service that I am working on. The controller supports async but I can't seem to find any good examples on how to load a DataGridView async while pulling data from the OData service. I did find this link which has me some what there but I don't know how to finish the rest because I currently have to convert the DataServiceQuery into a list or the DataSource fails.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756367(v=vs.110).aspx 
My code is something like this.

```
Private Sub getDataButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles getDataButton.Click
    ' Define the delegate to callback into the process 
    Dim callback As AsyncCallback = AddressOf OnLogsQueryComplete

    ' Define the query to execute asynchronously that returns  
    ' all customers with their respective orders. 
    Dim query As DataServiceQuery(Of LogServiceReference.Log) = (From log In context.Logs
                                                                   Select log)

    ' Begin query execution, supplying a method to handle the response 
    ' and the original query object to maintain state in the callback.
    DataGridView1.DataSource = query.BeginExecute(callback, query)
End Sub

Private Function OnLogsQueryComplete(ByVal result As IAsyncResult) As List(Of LogServiceReference.Log)
    ' Get the original query from the result. 
    Dim query As DataServiceQuery(Of LogServiceReference.Log) = _
        CType(result.AsyncState, DataServiceQuery(Of LogServiceReference.Log))

    Return query.EndExecute(result).ToList()
End Function
```

I can read / code either C# or VB, so if you have examples of either I am all ears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not truly populating a grid row-by-row async, it is populating the entire datasource async. Here is the code I used.

```
Private gridRows As List(Of LogServiceReference.Log) = New List(Of LogServiceReference.Log)()
Private Delegate Sub UpdateUI()
Private oUpdateUI As UpdateUI

Private Sub getDataButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles getDataButton.Click
    Try
        gridRows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

        oUpdateUI = New UpdateUI(AddressOf DoUpdateUI)

        ' Define the delegate to callback into the process 
        Dim callback As AsyncCallback = AddressOf OnLogsQueryComplete

        ' Define the query to execute asynchronously that returns  
        ' all customers with their respective orders. 
        Dim query As DataServiceQuery(Of LogServiceReference.Log) = (From log In context.Logs
                                                                       Select log)

        ' Begin query execution, supplying a method to handle the response 
        ' and the original query object to maintain state in the callback.
        query.BeginExecute(callback, query)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DoUpdateUI()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = gridRows
End Sub

Private Sub OnLogsQueryComplete(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
    ' Get the original query from the result. 
    Dim query As DataServiceQuery(Of LogServiceReference.Log) = _
        CType(result.AsyncState, DataServiceQuery(Of LogServiceReference.Log))

    ' Complete the query execution. 
    For Each log As LogServiceReference.Log In query.EndExecute(result)
        gridRows.Add(log)
    Next

    Invoke(oUpdateUI)
End Sub
```